# Google Maps REST API

Tags: android, google-maps

I've just made an App which uses Google Maps. Therefore I had to enter my SHA 1 KEY for the maps to work on the emulator.

Due to the App containing my SHA 1 KEY, Google Maps will only work on my computer (I know why) But how do I allow all users to use Google Maps on their phone without me adding everyone's SHA 1 KEY?

If anyone knows the answer or could direct me on the right path I would really appreciate any help given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I allow all users to use Google Maps on their phone without me adding everyone's SHA 1 KEY?

By creating a release apk signed with a real (not debug) keystore.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html